# Migrate postgresql JSON array of IDs to Mongodb ObjectID

Tags: java, json, mongodb, postgresql, database-migration

I'm trying migrate from postgres db to mongodb. I've a field JSON in postgres table, which has key and value pairs. I need to fetch the value based on JSON key and convert those values(values are basically postgres id) to Mongo objectID and then map those to mongo document.
JSON field looks like this

```
"B":["956c5b0a5341d14c23ceed071bf136f8"]}
```

I've written a function in java to convert postgres ID column to mongoID.

```
public String convertIDToMongo(String colName){
    ---encoding logic
}
```

This is working when the field is explicitly available in the table and also if the field datatype is not an array. In case of JSON and array, is there a way to fetch set of values from JSON field and convert them into Mongo Object ID?

````
"Select json::json->'A' from table" ``` 

gives me the value ["06992a6fef0bcfc1ede998ac7da8f08b","7d1d55e1078191e53244c41d6b55b3a3","31571835c6600517f4e4c15b5144959b"] But I need some help to convert this list of IDs to Mongo Object IDs. Below is how I convert for non JSON field with one postgres ID value to Mongo ID.
````

"Select " + convertIDToMongo('colName') + " as "_id", \n" +

```
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.
```

Comment: Welcome!   Do you actually *need* to convert to a MongoDB ObjectId()?   If you do not set `_id` in the `java.util.Map` that you intend to insert into MongoDB, the Java driver will create one for you.

Comment: Yes I need to, because this is not only for _id field, there are other fields which has object ID as values in mongo. Those values need to be converted from postgres ID to mongoID

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON array, then call your converter for each item in the array.   There are many JSON parsing options available.

Comment: Can you please explain with any code, as I'm new to postgresql. Thanks

Comment: This is beyond the scope of question particularly due to connection and driver class details.   I recommend searching for "postgres java select JSON column example"